# What happens if a non-diabetic receives an injection of insulin?

Tags: metabolism, diabetes-mellitus, insulin, blood-sugar

If a person without diabetes or any diabetes-related issues receives an injection of insulin, what happens? Would the blood glucose level drop or does the body naturally compensate for the added insulin? What biological process occurs?

Comment: I tried to clarify your question text a bit - FYI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Blood sugar drops (Hypoglycaemia)
2. There are several other uses of insulin (other than diabetic treatment)

**Some of those could be:**

- Diagnostics
- Psychology (Narcoanalysis)
- Parenteral nutrition
- Cardiology (Glucose–insulin–potassium solution (GIP or GIK solution) is given   after a myocardial infarction)
- Malignancy (Insulin potentiation therapy (IPT))
- Psychiatry (Deep insulin coma therapy (DICT))

---

<sub>Sources:</sub>

- <sub>Niazi, Asfandyar Khan, and Shaharyar Khan Niazi. "A Grand Dame
  with Hidden Aces: The Non-diabetic Uses of Insulin." Indian Journal
  of Endocrinology and Metabolism. Medknow Publications & Media Pvt
  Ltd. Web. 06 Feb. 2016.</sub>
- <sub>http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3354952/.</sub>
- <sub>"Hypoglycemia." Hypoglycemia. Web. 06 Feb. 2016.
  http://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/health-topics/Diabetes/hypoglycemia/Pages/index.aspx.</sub>

Comment: Insulin coma therapy is, as far as I know, one of the things like lobotomy. Sure, patients got more "manageable", but to call it psychiatry nowadays is a mistake.

Comment: @Mołot according to "Indian J Endocrinol Metab. 2012 Mar; 16(Suppl1): S57–S59."
 "schizophrenia patients were injected with insulin to induce severe hypoglycaemia for 10–15 minutes. Thereafter, the hypoglycaemia was reversed by infusing glucose". however, you are correct it cant be referred to as psychiatry nowadays, simply due to the reason of it being discredited in the late 1950s.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to overdose and die of an insulin injection. Obviously, if enough is injected fast enough, the body can't recompense appropriately and and the person would die of hypoglycaemia. Below around 20mg/dL of blood sugar levels in the blood you are likely to suffer brain damage and eventually death.

Answer (score -1):

depends on how much injected, you could just feel lightheaded or you might get yourself into an insulin induced coma, serious cases, yeah, one could die. There's a certain blood insulin level that the body can naturally compensate to maintain homeostasis, like I said before, depends on the injected amount. sidenote - Watch 'A Beautiful Mind', it shows the usage of insulin shock therapy (insulin coma therapy (ICT)) to "reduce" schizophrenia.

Comment: Any sources to add?